# Check if terminal supports unicode in rust

Tags: unicode, terminal, rust

I would like some way of doing essentially the following:

```rust
if supports_unicode {
    print!("some unicode");
} else {
    print!("ascii");
}
```

Is there any way in rust to check if the output supports unicode?

## Update

I found a way to check if the *device* supports unicode, but it doesn't check if the current output is set to the correct encoding, nor does it check if the font supports the full range of unicode characters. If you're curious, it uses the crate [`locale-codes 0.3.0`](https://crates.io/crates/locale-codes), and the code is

```rust
locale_codes::codeset::all_names().contains(&String::from("UTF-8"))
```

But, as I said, this doesn't solve my problem

Also, if you want, here is a more specific example of the problem I've been having. In the VSCode intergrated terminal (Windows 10 x64, VSCode 1.47), if I run a rust program that prints the character  (`U+1D465`), I get a variety of results, such as:

- It actually printing the correct character
- It prints �
- It prints nothing at all
- It prints  (`U+1D435`)

I hope this example helps.

Comment: I'm very interested on the answer (specific about terminal). You can get some information asking the locale (codeset part)

Comment: I found this related thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184345/detect-how-much-of-unicode-my-terminal-supports-even-through-screen ; I believe nowadays most applications just assume that the terminal supports unicode.

Comment: @Aloso it's a fair assumption on Unixes. On Windows, not so much.

Comment: @LiamBloom, by “Unicode” I'm assuming you mean UTF-8 specifically?

Comment: @mcarton Yes, I mean UTF-8

Comment: As for windows, maybe the way to go is this https://web.archive.org/web/20130101094000/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx